# Resources in a static lib file - MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, resources, static-libraries

MFC is failing to launch my dialog boxes, it seems, because it can't find the resource identifiers. The dialog boxes are in a separate .lib file (so it has a separate .rc file, which, I'm assuming, somehow conflicts with the one in my .exe file). How should I be handling this situation?

Comment: Can you give more details about how it is "failing to launch"? What are the specific symptoms?

Comment: I would call DoModal, and nothing would happen. Stepping in to the DoModal function revealed that the resource wasn't able to be loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the .rc file for the .exe file, add a line like this:

```
#include "YourLibResourceFile.rc"
```

Then, in the .exe's project settings, add an additional include directory to where YourLibResourceFile.rc is, in Resources/Additional Include Directories.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store resources (.rc files contents) in a static library. And since you can have only one "main" .rc file, all other .rc files mst be included in that one using an `#include` statement, such as explained by Smashery (Edit: Oh! Smashery, you are the OP!).

Comment: Yeah, I discovered this accidentally by myself =P Thanks for your answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your resource IDs are unique.

Comment: This requirement is made up. You can have a bitmap resource with the same ID as that of a dialog resource, for example. You can also have several child controls in dialogs that have the same ID, even within the same dialog (common for STATIC controls). While following your advice is safe, it needlessly limits the total number of resources you can use in a project.

Comment: I guess this answer made sense to me at the time, but this was 6yrs ago. I can't figure out why this would affect OP's problem. Tempted to delete this answer, but it's had one upvote which indicates it helped someone.....